# Delete file after download with response in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, download, cakephp-2.0, delete-file

My system creates temporary files and send them to download. That part works very well. The problem is that I want to delete those files from file system after user download the file or just after in some point in the time, but seems to afterFilter() function which is the last controller method to run, executes even before the file is downloaded, so is not a posibility or I'm missing something.

I have these functions in a DowloaderController

```
public function download() {
   $fileName = $this->Session->read('nameFile');

   if (!is_file(STORAGEPATH . $fileName)) {
      return;
   }

   $this->response->file( STORAGEPATH . $fileName );
   $this->response->download($fileName);
   return $this->response;
}
```

and

```
public function afterFilter() {
    if ($this->Session->check('nameFile')) {
        if (is_file(STORAGEPATH . $this->Session->read('nameFile'))) {
            @unlink(STORAGEPATH . $this->Session->read('nameFile'));
        }
        $this->Session->delete('nameFile');
    }
}
```

In a previous version of cake, i used to use something like:

```
    $this->viewClass = 'Media';

    $params = array(
        'id' => $fileName,
        'name' => $fileAlias,
        'download' => true,
        'extension' => $extension,
        'path' => $path
    );

    $this->set($params);
```

and worked well, but now it doesnt

Is there any way to unlink the temporary file just after this was dowloaded?

or

what you have done to solve this problem?

Using cakephp 2.8

Comment: There isn't a way from PHP to know when a file has finished downloading. Once you read the file back to the client, php is done whether the client is done saving the file or not. The client side doesn't signal back to the server to say "I'm done" either.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that, i didnt know it. ok ok, but must be another way to control these files i think, i mean not using an event or a callback from cake if they cant control the action. im gonna try using a header Location and redirect to another method with the response, but i dont really want to do a redirect cause its a download action. So knowing this, do you think could be another way to go or alternative, for solving this peculiar situation?

Comment: You need to run the cron job to delete temporary files (only delete old files).

Comment: Thanks @Manmohan is there a command to do that?, sorry i´m new with those jobs through cron. I´ve searched and not sure if what you tell me its related with that part of creating a shell and execute something in terminal. can you explain me a little more please

Comment: Please have a look on this link http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no way to know when the file download was finished and I do not have free access to the server following your comments, I ended up creating this function to delete all files except the last 5 sorted by date modified (just in case of multiple downloads by different users) when another download is called.

Using in the controller:

```
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
```

---

```
protected function _clearTemporaryFiles() {
   $dir = new Folder(STORAGEPATH);
   $files = $dir->find('.*', true);
   if (count($files) > 5 ) {
       foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
           $file = new File($dir->pwd() . DS . $file);
           $files[$key] = array();
           $files[$key]['name'] = $file->name() . '.' . $file->ext();
           $files[$key]['lastUpdate'] = $file->lastChange();
           $file->close();
       }

       $orderedFiles = Set::sort($files, '{n}.lastUpdate', 'asc');
       $orderedFiles = array_splice($orderedFiles, 0, count($orderedFiles) - 5);
       foreach ($orderedFiles as $archivo) {
           $archivo = new File($dir->pwd() . DS . $archivo['name']);
           $archivo->delete();
           $file->close();
       }
   }
}
```

It is not the most efficient solution, or would have wanted to use, but somehow solve my problem. The only concern is the possibility of downloads at the same time , but it would be a rare case that were more than 5 at a time.